# Jquery ready() vs simple function call before </body>

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I'm calling my JS scripts just before the closing body tag, is there a difference between using jQuery ready function like `$(myfunc());` vs just using simply `myfunc();` ?

Comment: I assume with `$(myfunc())` you actually mean `$(myfunc)`.

Comment: Was my example not a valid shorthand? Well I mean:

$(document).ready(function() {
   myfunc();
});

vs

myfunc();

Comment: Depends on what you understand by valid. `$(myfunc())` will execute `myfunc` and pass the return value to `$()`. As long as `myfunc` returns a function, it is fine. But it is not the equivalent to calling `myfunc` at the end of the page. That would `$(myfunc)`.

Comment: @FelixKling Invoking functions inside argument lists of other function invocations? That shouldn't even be considered as a pattern.

Comment: @IMB `$(x());` and `$(function () { x(); });` are not the same. In the firste case the function is invoked immediately, and in the second case it's invoked on DOM-ready. This is the proper way to pass a function inside the DOM-ready handler: `$(x);`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I'm not saying it is a pattern, but it is not uncommon. Consider `element.addEventListener('click', getListener(x))`, maybe in a loop, to create a new scope for `x`...

Comment: @Šime Vidas, if I need to pass a parameter in the function, I guess I need to wrap it first in a new function that has no parameter?

Comment: @IMB: Yes, you are passing an anonymous function which just calls the other function and passes the parameters.

Comment: @IMB Yes, this: `$( function () { x( param ); });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one difference would exist:

When you use `$(function(){...})` (short for`$(document).ready(function(){...})`, you're automatically wrapping the code in an anonymous function, thus creating a private scope. Variables defined using `var` inside this scope aren't leaked to the global scope.

```
<script>
$(function(){ //<-- Anonymous function wrapper
   var test = 1; //"Private" variable
   alert(test); //Alert: 1
});
alert(window.test); //Nothing
</script>
<body>
```

Versus

```
<script>
var test = 1;
alert(test); //Alert: 1
alert(window.test); //Alert: 1
</script>
</body>
```

---

When you don't wrap the function call in a wrapper, both approaches have a similar result:

```
<script>
$(myfunc);
</script></body>

</bodY><script>
myfunc();
</script>
```

Comment: Is it safe to say that unless I really need "advanced" jquery features, I'm better off using: `<script>myfunc();</script></body>` instead of `$(myfunc);` or `window.onload = myfunc;` ?

My goal is to make sure DOM is loaded before myfunc gets executed.

Comment: If you want to execute your code once the DOM is ready, don't consider `window.onload`. The advantage of `$` is that it can be defined anywhere. The advantage of a plain `myfunc()` is that it is not dependent on jQuery (=an external framework).